# Dojox grid Datagrid "Sorry, an error occured"

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I have valid `Datagrid` defined on the page with attached `ItemFileWriteStore` and normally it show data.

However as soon as data will contain (almost) duplicate entry, I will see `Sorry, an error occurred`.

I the code I do not see any data fields definitions beyond `DataGrid` columns definitions.

I suppose that store and/or `DataGrid` components balk at duplicates, but I do not know how can I change data to avoid those duplicates.

PS my data contain 6 columns duplicates differ only by 3rd column. Is position important? Do sore/datagrid expect 1rst column to be unique? Or first defined datagrid column to be unique?

**Dojo: 1.4**

Comment: create jsfiddle, sample or add code here....

Answer (score 1):

Did you set identifier? You need something unique (ID) to differentiate datastore items.
for example:

```
var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
        data: {
            identifier: "id",
            items: [
                {id: 1, name: 'A'},
                {id: 2, name: 'B'},
                {id: 3, name: 'c'}
            ]
        }
    });
```

you need to tell the store that your 3rd column is your identifier

Comment: Definition of datagrid only contained HTTP endpoint. No definition of data.

Comment: so how do you set data for grid?